# Facebook Util.java no log in eclipse logcat

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authorization

I am working on facebook sso android. I am having problems with keyhash ([White blank screen on using facebook android sso](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12660230/white-blank-screen-on-using-facebook-android-sso)). Facebook's android guide says to edit sdk's Uti.java `private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = true;` I have set it to true. However, there is no log coming in the logcat with tag Android Key Mismatch in which it shows which key was sent to facebook. 
Please help.

Comment: the tag should be: Facebook-authorize